# Google Material Expansion Panel

Tags: angular-material

I want to create an expansion panel like the one [in the demo](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/expansion-panels.html). I don't see where the api for this is. How is it invoked?

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for!  I don't find any example/api to achieve this.  Any luck so far?

Comment: No luck. I am constantly in awe at how google seems to often dare people to properly use its tools. Images instead of working examples, components with no explanation of how to code them or use them, the list goes on and on.

Comment: Googles Material Design is a theoretical concept. There are people working on actual implementations of the components mentioned on the material design website such as [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/). However they have yet to implement all components, the expansion panel for example is not yet implemented.

Answer (score 1):

There's one built into the sidenav on the angular material site: https://material.angularjs.org/. It's not offered as a separate component, but the source is there.

Also, this was a planned feature at one point in time, but was marked as deprecated recently: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/985.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an expansion panel using Google's AngularDart components. A demo and the docs are linked from their [github](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components).

Here's an [excerpt from the API docs](https://webdev.dartlang.org/components/api/angular_components/MaterialExpansionPanel-class):

> A material-styled expansion-panel.
>
> One or more panels are grouped together in a expansion-panel-set. When a > panel is clicked on, the panel contents expand. A panel
>   consists of a name, a value, optional secondary text, and the expanded
>   panel contents.
>
> Content element with attribute value will be used as the "value" of
>   the panel contents when it is in a collapsed state
>
> Interactions with a panel are done through the parent expansion-set.
>   The set takes into account the state of the other panels in the set,
>   and issues the appropriate actions onto each individual panel.
>
> TODO(google): Keyboard/accessibility inputs
>
> Example usage:
>
> ```
> <material-expansionpanel (save)="doSave()">
>   <my-component></my-component>
> </material-expansionpanel>
>
> <material-expansionpanel wide>
>   <div value class="valueClass">
>     Fancily formatted value of my panel's contents
>   </div>
>   <my-component></my-component>
> </material-expansionpanel>
> ```

Comment: Please don't provide link-only answers; instead, put most important bits to your answer directly. This way, the answer stays relevant even if the link gets broken and also is more friendly to those who read it.

Comment: @YakovL Thanks for the tip. I've added an excerpt from the API docs.